# Cisco ASA - replace default gateway in production

Tags: cisco, cisco-asa

For reasons like hsrp on a pair of border routers, I need to replace the default gateway on a Cisco ASA. Ideally, I'd like to do it with no noticable downtime (a few lost packets would be OK). I suppose I could add a second "0/0" route to the other ip with a higher metric, and simply remove the lowered metric route. Is this advisable, or are there a better way of doing it?

```
# currently
route outside 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 100.50.0.13 1

# plan
route outside 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 100.50.0.14 2
no route outside 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 100.50.0.13 1
```

The addresses are on the same subnet. A pair of routers speaking bgp with transit providers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your plan looks pretty good... the only suggestion for minimal downtime would to add a ping of the new HSRP address...

```
! currently: route outside 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 100.50.0.13 1
! ping ensures there is no possibility to need an ARP for the new NH
ping 100.50.0.14
conf t
route outside 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 100.50.0.14 2
no route outside 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 100.50.0.13 1
!!! Optional
!      This leaves the new default at a distance of 1...
route outside 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 100.50.0.14 1
no route outside 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 100.50.0.14 2
end
wr mem
```

Obviously if the HSRP gateway was just turned up, you'll get a gratuitous ARP from HSRP and the ping is not required... if not, the ping will ensure you don't have to buffer traffic while the ARP is answered (which wouldn't be very long anyway.